# bluimp Gallery implementation - HTML nor JS rendered

Tags: javascript, html, gallery, blueimp

I've created a simple webpage that will display images via a gallery plugin. After a very straightforward implementation, the page renders with no output where gallery mark up should be present.

I am using blueImp gallery, and have followed the setup instructions here - as far as 'controls' https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery#description

all relevant css, JS and img directories have been merged on the webpage directory.

Markup below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="js/blueimp-gallery.min.js" async></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" async></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" async></script>
        <script src="js/script.js" async></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/blueimp-gallery.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    </head>

    <body>


        <div id="main">
            <div class="navbar-wrapper" style="border: 12px solid black;">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Wilhelm Reich</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>

        <!-- The Gallery as lightbox dialog, should be a child element of the document body -->
        <div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-controls">
            <div class="slides"></div>
            <h3 class="title"></h3>
            <a class="prev">‹</a>
            <a class="next">›</a>
            <a class="close">×</a>
            <a class="play-pause"></a>
            <ol class="indicator"></ol>
        </div>

        <div id="links">
            <a href="img/1.jpg" title="LittleMan"></a>
            <a href="img/2.jpg" title="LittleMan"></a>
            <a href="img/3.jpg" title="LittleMan"></a>
        </div>

        <script>
        document.getElementById('links').onclick = function (event) {
            event = event || window.event;
            var target = event.target || event.srcElement,
                link = target.src ? target.parentNode : target,
                options = {index: link, event: event},
                links = this.getElementsByTagName('a');
            blueimp.Gallery(links, options);
        };
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by adding the thumbnail image source to the markup. Although in the documentation it states this optional.

> Create a list of links to image files, optionally with enclosed
>   thumbnails and add them to the body of your webpage, before including
>   the Gallery script: